# Prove that there exists $\gamma \in (a,b)$ such that $f \circ f(\gamma)=\gamma$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, continuity, monotone-functions

If $a,b,c \in R$ such that $a<b<c$ and $f:R \to R$ is a continuous function satisfying $f(a)=b,f(b)=c,f(c)=a$, then there exists $\gamma \in (a,b)$ such that $(f \circ f)(\gamma)=\gamma$

**My try**:
We have $f(a)=b, f(b)=c$ $\implies$ $f \circ f(a)=c$.

But $a=f(c)$, so we get $f \circ f \circ f(c)=c$

Similarly $f \circ f \circ f(b)=b$ and $f \circ f \circ f(a)=a$.

Now since $a<b<c$ we have $f \circ f \circ f(a)<f \circ f \circ f(b)<f \circ f \circ f(c)$

So this means $f \circ f \circ f(x)$ is strictly increasing in $(a,b)\cup[b,c)$ and so it is One-One.

Now since $f \circ f \circ f$ is One-One, that means $f \circ f$ is also One one which means $f$ is One-One.

But how to show that there exists $\gamma \in (a,b)$ such that $f \circ f(\gamma)=\gamma$

Comment: Use `\circ` to get $\circ$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that your idea does not work.
$$
 f(f(f(a))) < f(f(f(b))) < f(f(f(c)))
$$
for $a < b < c$ does not imply that $f \circ f \circ f$ is strictly increasing on $[a, b]$. Also the conclusion that $f$ is one-to-one cannot be correct because $f(a) < f(b)$ and $f(b) > f(c)$.

Instead use that
$$
 f(f(a)) = c > a \\
 f(f(b)) = a < b
$$
implies that $f(f(x)) - x$ has a zero in $(a, b)$, due to the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Yes i agree with you, it may not be strictly increasing.

Comment: Thank you... This question was in my homework in a bit modified form and I was having a hard time solving it. If not for Approach$0$, I won't have found this post. Even Google or Bing are better than this site's native search function.